# How can i get the row that is already deleted using Oracle Data Change Notification?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently working on a data change notification in my project and  I need to retrieve the rows that are modified ( INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) using Ora DCN.

I don't have any problem with INSERT/UPDATE operation, my problem is when a row is deleted. I want to retrieve the rows that are deleted so that I can update a backup database in separate server.

FYI: I don't want to use a trigger for this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Before deleteing a row.Insert that row to a back up table and after inserting .Delete that row.
Ex..

```
INSERT INTO backup_table
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the use case for DCN.  Its prime function is to allow external apps to keep their caches up-to-date.

Triggers constitute an appropriate mechanism for doing what you need, so it's a bit puzzling that you don't want to use them.

Alternatively there is Flashback Archive, it you have the appropriate database edition (before 11.0.2.4 it requires an additional license purchase).  [Find out mor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm#BJFFDCEH)e.